# Animate weapon ontouch

Tags: android, animation, touch, media-player

Hello everyone I would like to implement a method to touch on my image of a ak47, I have written the code but the method does not work on touch as it should. I would like that if you touch the gun that starts the repetition in my code. Thanks in advance

```
package org.realgunshot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class B2 extends Activity   {



ImageView bulletshot,bulletempty ;

Boolean click=true;

TextView Display;
Button b1;
int counter = 15 ;
Object mediaPlayerspara,mediaPlayersload;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.b2);
bulletshot=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bulletshot);
bulletempty=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bulletempty);



b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
Display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);



final Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.gun);
final Animation animgunshot = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.gunshot);
final Animation animbulletempty = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bulletempty);



b1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {





counter --;
Display.setText(""+counter);

if(counter <= 0)
{
counter=1;

mediaPlayerspara = null;

mediaPlayersload = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.sload);
((MediaPlayer) mediaPlayersload).setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayersload) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

mediaPlayersload.start();

mediaPlayersload.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayersload) {
mediaPlayersload.release();

 };
 });
}
});
}
else{

bulletshot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
bulletshot.startAnimation(animgunshot);

Handler handlers = new Handler(); 
handlers.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
public void run() { 
bulletshot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
bulletempty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} 
}, 300); 

bulletempty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
bulletempty.startAnimation(animbulletempty);

Handler handlers2 = new Handler(); 
handlers2.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
public void run() { 
bulletshot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
bulletempty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} 
}, 2000); 

v.startAnimation(animRotate);
final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ak47_1);
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
public void run() { 
button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ak47_0); 
 } 
}, 100); 




mediaPlayerspara = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.ak47);
((MediaPlayer) mediaPlayerspara).setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayerspara) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

mediaPlayerspara.start();

mediaPlayerspara.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayerspara) {
mediaPlayerspara.release();

};
});
}
});}
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){



return true;
}
return false;



}

});







Button apri = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadoadd);
apri.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.loadoadd, null);  



final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

 popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);

Button chiudi1 = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);

chiudi1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub




popupWindow.dismiss();

}});


 Button load = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.load);
 load.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
counter = 15;
Display.setText(""+counter);

}});

Button add = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.add);
add.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){



 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
counter = 1015;
Display.setText(""+counter);

}});
if (click){
popupWindow.showAtLocation(chiudi1, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

click=false;
}else{
popupWindow.dismiss();
click=true;
}     

}});








     }
}
```

Comment: your code is impossible to read! try formatting it and edit your question, please.

Comment: What should I change? this is my complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package org.realgunshot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class B2 extends Activity   {












ImageView proiettilesparo,proiettilevuoto ;

    Boolean click=true;

    TextView Display;
    Button b1;
    int contatore = 15 ;
     Object mediaPlayerspara,mediaPlayerscarica;









    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.b2);
        proiettilesparo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.proiettilesparo);
        proiettilevuoto=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.proiettilecade);



        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        Display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contatore);



        final Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pistola);
        final Animation animsparoproiettile = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.sparoproiettile);
        final Animation animproiettilecade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.proiettilecade);



        b1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            private Handler mHandler;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                 switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (mHandler != null) return true;
                    mHandler = new Handler();
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mAction, 1);

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (mHandler == null) return true;
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mAction);
                    mHandler = null;

                    break;
                }

                        return false;



            }
          Runnable mAction = new Runnable() {
              @Override public void run() {
                  contatore --;
                  Display.setText(""+contatore);

                  if(contatore <= 0)
            {
                    contatore=1;

                    mediaPlayerspara = null;

                    mediaPlayerscarica = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.scarica);
                    ((MediaPlayer) mediaPlayerscarica).setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayerscarica) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                mediaPlayerscarica.start();

                                mediaPlayerscarica.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayerscarica) {
                                        mediaPlayerscarica.release();

                                    };
                                });
                                    }
                                });
                     }
                  else{

                      proiettilesparo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        proiettilesparo.startAnimation(animsparoproiettile);

                        Handler handlers = new Handler(); 
                        handlers.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                             public void run() { 
                                 proiettilesparo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                 proiettilevuoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                             } 
                        }, 300); 

                        proiettilevuoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        proiettilevuoto.startAnimation(animproiettilecade);

                        Handler handlers2 = new Handler(); 
                        handlers2.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                             public void run() { 
                                 proiettilesparo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                 proiettilevuoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                             } 
                        }, 2000); 

            b1.startAnimation(animRotate);
            final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ak47_1);
            Handler handler = new Handler(); 
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() { 
                     button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ak47_0); 
                 } 
            }, 100); 




            mediaPlayerspara = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.ak47);
            ((MediaPlayer) mediaPlayerspara).setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayerspara) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        mediaPlayerspara.start();

                        mediaPlayerspara.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayerspara) {
                                mediaPlayerspara.release();

                            };
                        });
                            }
                        });}
                  mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
              }
          };

        });







        Button apri = (Button)findViewById(R.id.caricaoaggiungi);
          apri.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
               @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                   LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
                    final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.caricaoaggiungi, null);  



                    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

                   popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);

                             Button chiudi1 = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);

                             chiudi1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){



                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                      popupWindow.dismiss();

                     }});


                             Button carica = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.carica);
                             carica.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){



                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        contatore = 15;
                        Display.setText(""+contatore);

                     }});

                           Button aggiungi = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.aggiungi);
                            aggiungi.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){



                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         contatore = 1015;
                         Display.setText(""+contatore);

                     }});
                            if (click){
                                 popupWindow.showAtLocation(chiudi1, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                                 click=false;
                             }else{
                                 popupWindow.dismiss();
                                 click=true;
                             }     

               }});








     }
```

I changed it this way, but every time the animation starts from 0, there is a way to continue an action and does not stop and start it again?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone can help you - unless you post your code fully.  There are so many things missing...Your OnTouchListener doesn't even check for touch events such as ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take the action when user taps i.e.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            // Do your firing even
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //action when user removes finger.
            break;

        default:
            return false;

    } // end of switch case

    return true;
}
```

Also, just add a break point in onTouch() and debug to know what is happening and what part is not executing and fix it accordingly.